# How can a graph in visual studio for Noise Criteria Curve be made that can be re-sized dynamically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

Here is a rework of my question. Since it hasn't been answered.

**How can [this](http://asa.aip.org/classroom/curves.jpg) graph be made in visual studio that allows for it to be re-sized in a non web based application?** I have tried with WPF applications previously. At the current time the graph that is made is static and all points are plotted based on where it is in the window.

Issues that I can not seem to address:

- X axis is not constant and I can not set variables appropriately
- There are many labels for NC and no program I found allows for multiple label classes ie NC labels are labeled separately from measurements(squares and lines in link pic)
- Graph does not grow when making window bigger because it is drawn for each individual line not in graph formatting language

Comment: *I wish I could include a picture but I don't have enough points for that*... you can provide a link to an online image. And what *exactly* is your question?

Comment: @Sheridan I have updated my question for more clarity

Comment: I solved this graph with infragistics. [infragistics](http://http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms) doesn't have great documented code, or at least I had a hard time with it. However it works. It also isn't free. So hopefully your company or establishment has it already. I happened to use the 2008 version, so finding code or help was even harder.

Comment: Please add an answer with that information (and perhaps some additional information) and then accept it so that this question may be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms) has some nice charts, but the documentation is not great and the web service often has trouble pulling up pages.

A few things first:
 - I used Visual Studio 2008
 - You have to install the infragistic tools before you will see the chart option available
 - After tools are installed you will have NetAdvantage tab in Toolbox; I used UltraChart
These are needed:
using Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance; 
using Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles;

Some of the code:

```
DataTable mydata = new DataTable();
        // Define the columns and their names
        mydata.Columns.Add("Series Labels", typeof(string));
        mydata.Columns.Add("63", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("125", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("250", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("500", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("1k", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("2k", typeof(int));
        mydata.Columns.Add("4k", typeof(int));
        // Add the rows of data
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 50", 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 45", 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 40", 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 35", 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 30", 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "RC 25", 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "User Input", userInput[0], userInput[1], userInput[2], userInput[3], userInput[4], userInput[5], userInput[6] });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Rumble Limit", speechInterferenceLine + 25, speechInterferenceLine + 20, speechInterferenceLine + 15, speechInterferenceLine + 10, null, null, null });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Hissy Limit", null, null, null, null, speechInterferenceLine + 3, speechInterferenceLine + -2, speechInterferenceLine - 7 });
        mydata.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "Reference Line", speechInterferenceLine + 20, speechInterferenceLine + 15, speechInterferenceLine + 10, speechInterferenceLine + 5, speechInterferenceLine, speechInterferenceLine - 5, speechInterferenceLine - 10 });
```

Hope this helps someone.